# Reload DOM after change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a PHP page with a form, on click of the button i call another PHP page with an AJAX call. In the second PHP page is loaded a table with datatable plugin [DataTable](http://datatables.net/).

But this plugin not work because the DOM is changed. I call this as explain in the official site.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType" : "bs_full"
});
$('.datatable').each(function() {
    var datatable = $(this);
    // SEARCH - Add the placeholder for Search and Turn this into in-line form control
    var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');
    search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Cerca');
    search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
    // LENGTH - Inline-Form control
    var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
    length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');
});});
```

Can i force the reload of the DOM to run the plugin?

Comment: [Use datatables' built-in AJAX functionality instead](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: I use **"bProcessing" : true,** but don't work.